# What pins on a nRF51822 do I connect to a STM32 programmer?

Tags: stm32, flash, bluetooth-low-energy, firmware

I want to be able to program a [nRF51822](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4076) with [this programmer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2548) but I'm not sure what pins on the actual chip I should use, and all the guides seemed to be using a different chip

Comment: What you have is a module, not a chip.  You connect the SWD pins, ground, and target supply as a reference input to the programmer, except that what you have isn't a real STLINK, and so doesn't need a reference but unlike a real one can power the target if you like.  You'll have to consult the module's documentation to find SWCLK and SWDIO.  And yes, before someone unaware jumps in, you can in fact use an STLINK for this non-ST ARM Cortex M0.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: @ChrisStratton so if I had the chip already on a pcb and powered would I be able to have a debug port using just SWCLK and SWDIO?

Comment: And ground.  Provided it is running at approximately 3v3, otherwise you need a programmer with a target voltage buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chrisstratton has it right; connect SWDCK, SWDIO and GND to the appropriate pins on the programmer. You'll want to use software such as OpenOCD to talk to the nRF51822 using the ST-Link interface.

I've written a lot of software for these chips; if you're doing basic blinky stuff it's not too bad but if you want to use BLE and get into their soft devices there will be a bit of a learning curve because you must flash multiple images to different parts of the nRF51822 memory. If you were using a J-Link debugger it'd be a little easier as Nordic's tools understand how to talk to these programmers and will save you some initial headaches in getting your software, the soft device and (most likely) a bootloader into the memory without erasing the previous bits you've flashed.

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=openocd%20nrf51822&oq=openocd%20nrf51822) revealed links such as [this one](https://acassis.wordpress.com/2016/02/25/using-openocd-to-program-a-homebrew-nrf51822-board/) or this [Nordic Devzone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/4984/st-link-nrf51822-and-openocd) one which can help you get over the initial hurdles. Be patient, and start simple: blinky is always a good start.

DevZone used to be a *lot* better before they redesigned everything. Now it's a bit of a crapshoot to find info you want and navigating their terrible "Web 2.0" experience drives me mad, but perhaps you'll weather it better.