# Do I have to do anything special if I want to connect to a chip with SWD and SWDIO and nRESET are on the same pin?

Tags: flash, swd

I want to wire a [MDBT40-256RV3](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4076) to a SWD programmer and on the programmer nRESET and SWDIO are on separate pins but on this chip they share the same pin, so how should I wire that?

Comment: Why don't you ask the vendor? Adafruit is offering to sell you a J-Link along with the module; they must have some idea of how to connect the two.

Comment: This is an implicit part of the question you asked yesterday **about how to connect this same BLE module to an SWD programmer** https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445711/what-pins-on-a-nrf51822-do-i-connect-to-a-stm32-programmer you do not have to do anything special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wire SWD and SWDIO, leave nReset open.

This chip (NRF51xxxx) simply has no dedicated reset pin to connect to.

Comment: is there any way to reset it then?

Comment: Certianly via a DAP command.